# Is EasyMock's .times(x) method an issue for unit testing robustness?

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, easymock

I'm currently working on some unit tests for my application using JUnit and EasyMock for mocking complex objects, and I'm facing a **dilemma**. 
For instance, I'm testing each function with the following test template:

```
public static int foo(Object a){
// my function that needs to be tested

  int quantity = 0;
  if(a != null && a.getInt() != null ){
    quantity = a.getInt();
  }
  return quantity;

}

public void testFoo(){
// my unit test for the function foo
  int expectedValue = 0;
  int output = 0;

//Setting up my mocks
  Object a_mock = EasyMock.create(Object.class)
  EasyMock.expect(a_mock.getInt()).andReturn(null).times(1);
  EasyMock.expect(a_mock.getInt()).andReturn(1).times(2);

//Executing
  // Case 1: a is null
  expectedValue = 0;
  output = foo(null);
  assertEquals(expectedValue, output);

  // Case 2: a.getIn() is null
  expectedValue = 0;
  output = foo(a_mock);
  assertEquals(expectedValue, output);

  //Case 3: nominal case
  expectedValue = 1;
  output = foo(a_mock);
  assertEquals(expectedValue, output);

}
```

This structure works pretty well, but here is my point: unit testing is a testing process that allows you to validate if each unit (here a function) gives you the wanted output, knowing the input. This means that if I need to modify my function foo, but without modifying what it does, my unit tests still have to pass.
Theoretically, if foo is changed like this:

```
public static int foo(Object a){

  int quantity = 0;
  if(a != null && a.getInt() != null && a.getInt() != 5){ //modification here
    quantity = a.getInt();
  }
  return quantity;

}
```

Then testFoo still has to pass.
**But it doesn't**, because the `.times(2)` must be changed in `.times(3)`.

So here is my question : is the .times(x) method of EasyMock an issue for the robustness of unit tests ? And if no, then what is the minimal level of robustness a unit test must have ?

Comment: Could you possibly avoid mocking the methods at all?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60139201/performing-non-mock-state-based-unit-testing-of-non-trivial-functions-and-their/60196328#60196328

Answer (score 0):

First, as mentinoned in the comment, you may not need to pass a mock for `a` at all.  Maybe using some real instances of `Object` is simple enough and does not have any negative consequences on your tests.

Second, if you come to the conclusion that mocking is necessary, then you can avoid using `times` by providing individual mocks for each of the tests.  You only have to call times because you are re-using `a_mock` between different tests.

Going one step further, you should even consider splitting up your function `testFoo` into three different functions - or directly convert `testFoo` into a parameterized test with three parameter sets.